# C# LINQ select until amount >= 0

Tags: c#, linq

This is example database table

`Name     |   Quantanity
Book I   |  1
Book II  |  13
Book III |  5
etc...`

And I want to select this rows until I will have 100 books usinq LINQ expression.

I was trying

`.TakeWhile(x => (amount -= x.Quantanity) > 0);`

But it gave me an error

> "Expression tree cannot contain assignment operator"

Comment: Just write it with foreach

Comment: It doesn't work this way. How do you imagine it to be translated into SQL query? I guess, this problem should be solved by stored procedure or by using cursor / data reader.

Comment: @VladimirArustamian That was my first thought, too. But now I'm curious if it could be done with a lambda expression

Comment: did you actually meant to say `(amount - x.Quantanity) > 0`

Comment: @VladimirArustamian `foreach` will take all records from a database, and then iterate through them, isn't it?

Comment: What ORM are you using?

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev Yes, it will. Otherwise it wouldn't have access to the properties values.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev if OP cares about optimization, then your solution is much better, ofc.

Comment: @VladimirArustamian but if I do this with foreach i need at least 2 IQueryable objcects. It would be inefficeint, woudn't it?

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev Accualy I wrote all by my own. But in future I'm planning to use EF in this project

Comment: What if the next book-quantity would exceeed 100, you want to take a different book to match exactly 100 or you want to take say 99 or exceed the max-count?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I want to achieve something like best match. But I'm afraid that could be too hard for me.

Comment: @Kermax If you did this in SQL, this article covers a nice approach to get the best match : https://jaxenter.com/10-sql-tricks-that-you-didnt-think-were-possible-125934.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int bookCount = 0;
var query = books
   .OrderBy(b => b.Quantity) // to get count 100, otherwise exceed is likely
   .AsEnumerable()
   .Select(b => {
        bookCount += b.Quantanity;
        return new { Book = b, RunningCount = bookCount  };
    })
   .TakeWhile(x => x.RunningCount <= 100)
   .Select(x => x.Book);
```

Comment: This is a very nice solution! But could you explain why you order the `books` first?

Comment: If the `-=` operator is not supported (*Expression tree cannot contain assignment operator*), why do you think `+=` will be

Comment: @RomanoZumbé: he mentioned "I want to achieve something like best match. But I'm afraid that could be too hard for me." If you order by quantity first you have best chances to get exactly 100 books

Comment: @TimSchmelter Ah, ok. Thats makes sense.

Comment: Still "Expression tree cannot contain assignment operator"

Comment: @Kermax: try again with `AsEnumerable` as shown above. Note that this will use Linq-To-Objects and can cause all records to stream into your memory

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thank you. Probalby you saved the rest of my day or maybe more.

Answer (score 1):

Tim's solution is good, but note about it --- Only the part before the `AsEnumerable()` is being executed by the data server -- Basically, you are pulling the entire table into memory, and then processes it.

Let's see if we can improve that:

```
int bookCount = 0;

var query1 = (from b in books
         where b.Quantity > 0 && b. Quantity <= 100
         orderby b.Quantity
         select b).Take(100).AsEnumerable();


var query = query1
   .Select(b => {
        bookCount += b.Quantity;
        return new { Book = b, RunningCount = bookCount  };
    })
   .TakeWhile(x => x.RunningCount <= 100)
   .Select(x => x.Book);
```

This limits us to only 100 records in memory to look thru to get to a count of 100.

Comment: I will try your suggestion tomorrow and comment back how it works. Thanks